# Inserting hebrew text in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, hebrew

When i inserted hebrew text in my table this is what i get:

```
??????
```

i think that i tried everything and i really really lost.

i found here this tut:

> 1.the db collation has to be utf8_general_ci.
>
> 2.the collation of the table with hebrew has to be utf8_general_ci
>
> 3.in my php connection script i put header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
>
> 4.in my xhtml head tag i put
>
> 5.after selecting the db in the connection script i put mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

but is still not working for me.

picture:
http://oi60.tinypic.com/jq0rw7.jpg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Showing what you're trying might be helpful

Comment: Your server coallation is set to: utf8mb4_general_ci. Can this be utf8_general_ci?